# What's the proper way to determine whether a certain URL sits within a certain directory?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, url

I have a directory in my project that I want all calls to web pages within it and any sub directories to be diverted to another web site.

Eg.

If the directory is http://localhost/MyProject/MyDirectory, I want all URLs such as http://localhost/MyProject/MyDirectory/MyFile.aspx to be diverted to another web site.

I do not want to use IIS for this as there are some additional business rules relating to dates and stuff. There I was thinking of doing it in either my master page or in my global.cs file.

How though do I know whether the request is actually in the directory.

I was going to just go

if(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.contains("http://localhost/MyProject/MyDirectory) 
{
    Response.Redirect("...")
}

But I feel that's not that good of a solution since may be in different domain names etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Request.Url.AbsolutePath` to get the path after the domain name.